# Where to put and how to load result object class in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, code-organization

I'm looking for proper way to organize 'Result object classes' in CodeIgniter. These classes are usualy used in models as described in [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html):

> You can also pass a string to result() which represents a class to
>   instantiate for each result object (note: this class must be loaded)

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users;");

foreach ($query->result('User') as $row)
{
   echo $row->name; // call attributes
   echo $row->reverse_name(); // or methods defined on the 'User' class
}
```

So, where to put 'User' class and is there any 'offical' way how to load it?

Answer (score 3):

Try using a library.

Place your class in the application/libraries folder, then use the loader to load it:

```
$this->load->library('user');
```

Comment: Absolutly not, because that will create new instance of user class and I don't want to have that empty object in memory. And of course, result object classes aren't libraries at all.

Comment: The use $this->load file() to load a php file containing your classes

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are asking for, but I often use a MY_Model with:

```
public function merge_object(&$object, $data){

    if (is_object($data)) {
        $data = get_object_vars($data);
    }
    if (!empty($data)) {
        foreach ($data as $property => $value) {
            if (!property_exists($object, $property)) {
                $object->$property = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    return $object;
}
```

and then call $this->merge_object($this, $data); from the __construct($data = array())

When you call a model function now, it returns a an instance of the model class as well, and so you can access any of its methods. It does essentially what you are trying to do.